# Unable to use any Anaconda features even though its installed

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have installed Anaconda from its site and was working fine for sometime, however I needed to install Plotly and used the below steps mentioned in another site.
I just got it up and running on spyder 3.0 using the following steps. (windows 10)

> Download plotly using pip usig command line (python -m pip install plotly) this requires downloading python 3.5 separately from Spyder as well. (so far I haven’t had any conflicts)
> In Spyder, goto->Tools ->PYTHONPATH Manager -> addPath -> insert path to Plotly library (mine was in python\python36-32\Lib\site-packages), then synchronize
> Restart Spyder
> test it out with import plotly.plotly \n import plotly.graph_objs as go in a new .py scrypt
> Hope it works out for you.
> Cheers

After the above steps I was able to import plotly in Spyder and didn't face any issues, however after I restarted my machine I'm unable to run Anaconda navigator or Spyder.
I'm able to launch Anaconda prompt but any command executed returns different kinds of errors like

1. "conda install anaconda-navigator"

   > environment variables:
   > conda info could not be constructed.
   > KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
2. "spyder"

   > ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init*_.py)
3. anaconda-navigator

   > ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified module could not be found.

I tried every solution on internet like uninstalling and reinstalling, deleting all the trace files on anaconda and even the Environment variables seem to be fine

echo %PATH% command returns

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Python\Scripts;C:\Python;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\saish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin;C:\apache-zookeeper-3.7.0\bin;C:\Spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin;C:\hadoop\bin;C:\Users\saish\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\saish\AppData\Roaming\np
```

where python command returns

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

C:\Users\saish\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Please suggest any new measures other than the ones I have mentioned. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9356#issuecomment-577271046) github issue, you may have a conflict between dependencies of packages anaconda installed and the one you installed manually. Check your pythonpath and see if removing the pip folder from the pythonpath fixes the issue.

Comment: I have tried to change the PYTHONPATH variable to 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe as per some page, anything specific I should set this PYTHONPATH to?

Comment: @saishashankRayaprolu you should just remove the external pip directory.

Comment: I mean before posting the question I had already altered PYTHONPATH as above but still face the issue, there's no external pip directory right now in PYTHONPATH variable.
I have also removed them from PATH system variable and set it to 
'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts'

Comment: @saishashankRayaprolu, what's in your C:\Python directory? Is it another copy of python?

Comment: I have Python installation in there, however I have tried to uninstall python before installing Anaconda any cleanup I need to do here?
I must note here that this command echo %PATH% returns some paths very different from what I actually see in System variables

Comment: @saishashankRayaprolu well, if it is an extra python installation you aren't expecting, then you should remove it.

Comment: I mean I'm not sure if its an extra installation since I had uninstalled Python before installing anaconda

Comment: @saishashankRayaprolu you could try temporarily renaming that folder and see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Turns out this was the issue, I uninstalled everything Anaconda, Python but C:\Python wasn't going away, simply deleted it and reinstalled Anaconda.

Comment: Glad it worked out.